# prefers-color-scheme sample doesn't work but other pages work well with darkmode on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, darkmode

I am using Google Chrome 92.0.4515.131 on Windows 10.
I installed the Dark Mode extension for Chrome in order to quickly toggle between day/night mode.
Almost all web pages including StackOverflow work perfectly with Dark mode except samples copied from Internet!
I copied the sample below from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme
Just save it into an HTML file and open it in Chrome. Clicking on the DarkMode button the Chrome shows no change at all.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .day {
            background: #eee;
            color: black;
        }

        .night {
            background: #333;
            color: white;
        }

        @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
            .day.dark-scheme {
                background: #333;
                color: white;
            }

            .night.dark-scheme {
                background: black;
                color: #ddd;
            }
        }

        @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
            .day.light-scheme {
                background: white;
                color: #555;
            }

            .night.light-scheme {
                background: #eee;
                color: black;
            }
        }

        .day, .night {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 1em;
            width: 7em;
            height: 2em;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="day">Day (initial)</div>
    <div class="day light-scheme">Day (changes in light scheme)</div>
    <div class="day dark-scheme">Day (changes in dark scheme)</div> <br>

    <div class="night">Night (initial)</div>
    <div class="night light-scheme">Night (changes in light scheme)</div>
    <div class="night dark-scheme">Night (changes in dark scheme)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried other not-working sample codes although I cannot find a full and simple html sample to understand how to use prefers-color-scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good. But since the preferred color scheme is taken from your OS settings, the browser won't detect it unless it's set there. Most extensions just add their own background-color but obviously don't overwrite any of your OS settings.

Light mode activated in OS:
[image: Light mode activated in OS]

Dark mode activated in OS
[image: Dark mode activated in OS]

If you would want to individually activate dark or light mode on your page, you could do that with a separate button. There's a good example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_dark_mode

Hope I could help you a bit further.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is caused by the extension. I have to toggle dark mode using the OS setting. I upvoted but I don't have enough 'reputation' at this time.